# How to understand the execution plan of my query on BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am looking for detailed explanation on how to understand the execution plan of my query on BigQuery ? Basically,

1. How to read execution plan to understand which part of query is taking most time and needs to change ?
2. How to get slot info and how to use it to update my query ?
3. What is the difference between actual time taken by the query and total slot time (which is huge) ?

Please help.

I tried to go through https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-overview but it did not help much.

Comment: Here's an explanation : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-plan-explanation#an_example_query